# Electron: how to close a portable app on pulling out the pendrive

Tags: electron, portability

I made a portable app with electron. It works fine. I have it saved in a pendrive, so I don't need to install it and copy into my hard disk to run it. Just executing the app from the pendrive I have it running in my desktop. But what I need, is implement a system that makes that if you pull out the pendrive the app automatically closes. I've been googling something similar and found many ways for using a pendrive as a master key. But that isn't exactly what I need. I don't want to shutdown the PC, I only need to close the app and remove it from memory. There is any way or nodejs library that can help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a practical solution that could work on all platforms:

```
    const basePath = app.getAppPath()

    setInterval(() => {
        const path = basePath.split('/')
        const baseDir = path.slice(0, -1).join('/')

        fs.writeFile(baseDir + '/portable.txt', '1', err => {
            if(err) {
                app.quit()
            }
        })
    }, 1000)
```

The script above try to save a TXT file every second. If `fs.writeFile` returns an error, `app.quit()` is called closing the application.

Comment: Glad that you got cross-platform solution. But what happens if the `fs.writeFile` falis because of some other reason? It would be better if handle this case as well.

Comment: Sure! While itsn't an issue for the purpose I needed, it would be great to find a solution to you asking for. However it will always work pulling out the pendrive and that's fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`node_usbspy`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-usbspy) module to watch the usb insertion/removal. This module supports only Windows.

If you receive an event with `device_status` as 0 then you could quit the app with `app.quit()`

Hope it helps you!

Note: I'm the author of `node-usbspy`.

Comment: Thank you very much @Thaadikkaaran